# Es una ofensa para llamarle a alguien "Gabacho"?

Tags: vulgaridades, insultos

¿Es una ofensa llamar a alguien "Gabacho" en Mexico y en otros países donde el español se habla?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabacho

Comment: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=gabacho (curiosa la etimología, parecida a la que tiene "bárbaro").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desconozco sinceramente el origen del uso de este término en México, pero lo que te puedo decir es que lo usamos para referirnos a las personas de origen Estadounidense. No creo que sea puramente despectivo, mas bien depende del contexto con el que lo usas.De hecho es común escuchar en México que alguien se fué al `gabacho` para indicar que esa persona se fué a Estados Unidos, en dicho caso el término `gabacho` se usa para sustituir el propio nombre del país(Estados Unidos).
 Según mi experiencia esta palabra es usada como sinónimo de `gringo`. Remarco, este vocablo lo he escuchado(y utilizado muchas veces) en México(desconozco su significado y uso en otros paises).

Comment: En España "gabacho" se usa para los franceses. De hecho, la definición de diccionario excluiría a los "gringos". http://lema.rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=gabacho

Comment: @Flamma lee por favor bien mi respuesta y descubrirás que he especificado que este uso es aplicable en México de manera cotidiana. No sé realmente cómo es que ha llegado a adquirir ese significado en México ni si su definición oficial lo contradiga, lo único que he expuesto es su definición y uso en México.

Comment: No he pretendido corregir tu respuesta, ni señalar nada incorrecto en ella, sino complementarla.

Answer (score 7):

Gabacho es un modo despectivo de denominar a los franceses en español.

No tiene por qué tratarse directamente como un insulto, si bien su connotación es directamente despectiva.

Comment: ¿ Cómo se compara con "Franchute" ?

Comment: @jlliagre `Franchute` es mas despectivo todavía

Answer (score 5):

Al menos en España, absolutamente **sí**. *Gabacho* es el modo despectivo de referirse a un Francés, de igual forma que *Guiri* alude a una persona del norte de Europa, *Moro* a alguien del norte de África o *Sudaca* a alguien de America Latina.

Comment: Para latinoamérica también se oye mucho "_panchi_"

Comment: *Moro* procede directamente del latín *mauro*, con el mismo significado y sin ánimo peyorativo (incluso hay un país, Mauritania, cuyo nombre procede de esa palabra). Y *sudaca* fue un simple acortamiento de la palabra *sudamericano* usado en los años 70 sobre todo por los estudiantes de medicina para referirse a sus compañeros procedentes de Sudamérica, sin más. Otra cosa es que estas palabras luego hayan tomado una connotación negativa y, desde luego, es peligroso usarlas sin conocer bien el medio.

Comment: Nadie duda del origen etimológico de las palabras, pero eso no quita que, a día de hoy, sean palabras únicamente despectivas. Cuando a un marroquí se le llama Moro, le molesta. Cuando a alguien de la america latina se le llama Sudaca, le molesta, Etc. De hecho, suelen ir acompañadas de un  moro/sudaca/guiri "de mierda". Dicho de otra forma: No hay forma alguna en la que un Español pueda llamar Sudaca a un Peruano sin tono despectivo.

Comment: No pretendía corregirte, sino dar un poco de trasfondo sobre cómo algunas de estas palabras se convierten en ofensivas con el paso del tiempo (también hay casos de palabras ofensivas que se convierten en lo contrario). Desde luego, yo no usaría estas palabras salvo en un entorno en que se entendiera perfectamente que las uso en tono jocoso. Tengo un amigo francés a quien siempre llamamos *gabacho* o *franchute*, por ejemplo, pero entre amigos queda claro que es una broma. Fuera de ahí, son despectivas, sin duda.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, es un término que heredamos de los españoles, ellos lo usan para referirse a los franceses, aquí en México se usó por analogía para referirse a un extranjero rubio, y con el tiempo ya por costumbre se denominó así a nuestros vecinos del Norte. No tiene connotación racista ni peyorativa, simplemente es una manera informal de referirse a ellos o a lo que viene del Norte (Por ejemplo una camioneta "gabacha").